# How to set the system environment CLASSPATH variable in Windows 7

Tags: java

I am trying to set the CLASSPATH variable so that my java programs can access external jars.   All the jars are in one directory and using the Java 1.6 wildcard feature, I currently have assigned the CLASSPATH variable to this value:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\externaljars\*
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.   Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classpath is bad. You haven't to use the *. If the directory of your external jars are in the C:\Program Files\Java\externaljars you have just to add this path to your classpath like that:

> CLASSPATH = .;"C:\Program Files\Java\externaljars";

Comment: Readers should watch out that adding "." to the CLASSPATH will cause java to use jars in the current directory over other entries. Usually, this is desired behaviour, but not always (and it wasn't asked for in the question)

Comment: Sorry about the down vote. It was a mistake and the site wont let me undo it unless the answer is edited. Sorry

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\externaljars\*
```

Assuming externaljars is the directory that has all the jar files.

Comment: This is how the path is specified.   The HTML on stackoverflow removed the final backslash.