# Java program and mySQL connectivity issue: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, driver, connectivity

I've been having a problem with mySQL database connectivity. I'm getting an error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sakila.

I have installed mySQL workbench, and have the driver from here
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

I have saved mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin and set the classpath to

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin;

and started the mysql workbench where the database is found.

The code I am using is as follows: Which I am sure works, as I've asked a friend to test it form me. Unfortunately, we are developing on different platforms and could not instruct me as to how to fix this error. Has anyone an idea on how I can fix this?

```
public class Version {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sakila";
    //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";


    try {


        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from actor;");

        System.out.println("test");

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
}
}
```

}

EDIT: Problem sovled. Did not have .jar appended to the end of the bin file, which is necessary.

Comment: Can you specify how you set the classpath? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386372/how-to-set-the-system-environment-classpath-variable-in-windows-7) may give hints on how to set it - note the quotes around the entry because "Program Files" has a space in it

Comment: shouldn't you have a jar extension of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin" ?

Comment: thats the thing, the .bin file is of TYPE jar in the windows file descriptor, but not a .jar.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
```

right before the line "con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);"

All you need to do is load the driver class before getting the connection from the drivermanager.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I am now getting a class not found exception

Comment: In the classpath you should set the absolute path until the jar file name i.e C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin\<jar-name>.jar.

Comment: no jar file has come with the driver ive downloaded. I posted a link to the driver download page if you wish to take a look.

Comment: I downloaded the package from the same location and I can see the jar file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" inside the zip package. are you sure your zip contains no jar?

Comment: yes, this is the file I have been using, but the .jar is not in the actual file name itself. I will append the .jar into the classpath variable and see what happens.

Comment: are you using windows? "are the extensions of known files hidden" by any chance in your windows folder view settings?

Comment: htulsiani, i changed the extension to .jar and this worked fine. Really annoying error!! Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the driver before calling the getConnection :

```
String pdriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(pdriver).newInstance();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but now I am getting a class not found exception!

Comment: You need to add the jar library into your class-path. If you are using Eclipse : build path .

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the connector jar file to your `classpath` or `...\jre1.6.0\lib\ext`

```
Classpath is the one you should favor instead of the latter
```

Comment: I have already set the classpath as I have mentioned in the original post!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MySQL connecter library `jar file` to the classpath, rather than the directory where it is contained.

Are you not using an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse? Setting up a command line development environment in Windows is not hard but it's not trivial either

Comment: What do you mean by the JAR file? This is the file type of the .bin file I have set to the classpath. I am not using eclipse or netbeans for this project.

Comment: What is inside mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin?

Comment: it never opens. I posted a link to the driver i've downloaded if you wish to take a look.

Comment: The full name of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin" is actually "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" - this is the JAR file in question, and the one that contains the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.