# Matlab and MySQL no suitable driver found

Tags: mysql, matlab

I am trying to connect to MySQL database with the following code in Matlab, but I am getting the error message

> "No suitable driver found for 
>   jdbc:mysql://mydatabasehost.amazonaws.comMyDatabase"

```
databaseName = 'MyDatabase';
username = 'myusername';
password = 'mypassword';
jdbcDriver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver';
server = ' jdbc:mysql://mydatabasehost.amazonaws.com';

conn = database(databaseName, username, password, jdbcDriver, server);
```

I am using Matlab R2012 (64bit).
I have already downloaded and installed the JDBC connector for Windows from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
I have added it to classpath.txt of Matlab (alternatively use javaaddpath(location of the jdbc driver). Am I missing a step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java program and mySQL connectivity issue: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777880/java-program-and-mysql-connectivity-issue-no-suitable-driver-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok closing this question.

The issue is the spacing at the beginning

```
server = ' jdbc:mysql://mydatabasehost.amazonaws.com';
```

Also I should have included the port number

```
server = 'jdbc:mysql://mydatabasehost.amazonaws.com:3306/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) driver and put in classpath, extract the ZIP file and put the containing JAR file in the classpath.

**And try to use double quotes**