# Matlab - No suitable driver when connecting to localhost

Tags: postgresql, matlab, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a localhost setup PostgreSQL 10 with Matlab R2015a and after following the [instructions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/postgresql-jdbc-windows.html) and connection string layout, I'm at a loss to explain why I'm still getting a "No suitable driver found" error.

```
datasource = 'toronto';
username = 'postgres';
password = '********';
driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver';
server = 'jdbc:postresql://localhost:5432/';

connection = database(datasource, username, password, driver, server)
```

I've checked this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721269/matlab-and-mysql-no-suitable-driver-found) but no dice. Here's some extra information, hopefully someone has come across this before.

- PostgreSQL 10.1, build 1800 64-bit
- Java Version 8, built 1.8.0_91-b14
- PostgreSQL JDBC 4.2 Driver, 42.1.4

Comment: Your JDBC driver isn't on the classpath (Matlab can't find it). That is all your error message means, and all you must do to fix it.

Comment: That's the thing, I've already added it to the classpath with javaaddpath

Comment: And it didn't work. What is "javaaddpath"?

Comment: Can you verify that the right classpath is present using javaclasspath command? If so, try to add the class path in OS as well and restart your MATLAB. Hope that helps.

Comment: It adds jar files to the classpath: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaaddpath.html

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani Yeah I see it at the bottom.

Comment: Other quick fix is to copy driver jars to java ext lib folder.

Comment: Might be worth checking your jdbc drivers downloaded correctly too.

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani I've already tried that unfortunately

@ ElliottFrisch I have redownloaded them a few times. These should be the correct ones right? https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: If copying to ect lib is not working then you might have issues with java configuration as well. You can follow these steps to be sure:
https://au.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/configure-your-java-environment.html