# MySQL in dynamic project driver issue

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I have build a dynamic project and when I am trying to connect to MySQL i get the following error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/clouddb
```

I have inserted the Jar file into the Apache Tomcat lib folder since I run it on Server, as you can see in the picture below, but again the same message.

[image: This is the jar list]

After that I tried to insert the driver into the lib of `WEB-INF` folder and the driver was added automatically to Web App Libraries but again the same message.

Any advices where do I have to add it ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777880/java-program-and-mysql-connectivity-issue-no-suitable-driver-found?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I need to add the following:

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
```

just before the line:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Found this from Maverick's reply above.